# Handling Null Object Property Value in Component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to determine the best way to handle instances where a user may not have defined a value attached to the JSON object being used within my component. Should I be using a tertiary command to handle instances where `null` is present and throwing an error preventing my component from loading? Is there a best practice for these scenarios?

```
const RecordCard = props => {
    return (
            <div className="record-container">
                <RecordDate type={props.type} date={props.recordDateSlug} />
                <RecordHead linkId={props.recordIdHash} title={props.title} category={props.category.categoryName} user={props.synotate_user.fullNameSlug} picture={props.synotate_user.picture} dataDate={props.dataDateRangeSlug}/>
                <hr />
                <RecordBody discovery={props.discovery} />
                <RecordFooter reports={props.record_reports} files={props.record_files}/>
                <EditRecord linkId={props.recordIdHash} recordUser={props.user} user={props.user.userId} />
                <hr />
            </div>
    )
}
```

My `category={props.category.categoryName}` throws an error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of null
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to do it is to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with default values. `category` would default to an empty object if it wasn't there, and then `categoryName` would just be undefined and wouldn't throw an error:

```
const RecordCard = ({
  category: {
    categoryName
  } = {},
  synotate_user: {
    fullNameSlug,
    picture
  } = {},
  user,
  dataDateRangeSlug,
  title,
  recordIdHash,
  type,
  recordDateSlug,
  discovery,
  record_reports,
  record_files
}) => {
  const {
    userId
  } = user;
  return (
    <div className="record-container">
      <RecordDate type={type} date={recordDateSlug} />
      <RecordHead linkId={recordIdHash} title={title} category={categoryName} user={fullNameSlug} picture={picture} dataDate={dataDateRangeSlug}/>
      <hr />
      <RecordBody discovery={discovery} />
      <RecordFooter reports={record_reports} files={record_files}/>
      <EditRecord linkId={recordIdHash} recordUser={user} user={userId} />
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Based on your answer, how would I pass `props` in to replace the blank values if a value is present? I.e. I am passing a mapped object to `RecordCard`, which would be the `props` when building `RecordCard`